# How can I use a modal to add a point with a comment to a leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I'm trying to use leaflet to create a map where a user can leave a comment on a location. A user should be able to click the map to trigger a modal that prompts them to input a comment. A point/marker should be added to the map if they click the "Save" button in the modal.

My  issue is that if a user 1) clicks the map, 2) clicks "Cancel" on the modal, 3) clicks the map again, and 4) clicks the "Save" button this time then *all* the points get added to the map (including the ones where the user clicked "Cancel"). How can I fix this so that only a single point is added to the map (and geoJSON layer) if a user clicks the "Save" button?

Note: Once I figure out this issue, I will work on taking the input from textarea element (comment) in the modal and adding it to the geoJSON object.

Live example of the issue: https://sandbox.roylwells.com/leaflet/maptest3

**My HTML:**

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <h3>Leave a comment</h3>
        <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
        <form>
            <textarea id="comment" name="comment" maxlength="200">Enter your comment</textarea>
        </form>
        <button id="saveButton">Save</button>
        <button id="cancelButton">Cancel</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

**My Javascript code:**

```
// create empty geojson feature collection
    var comments = {
        type: 'FeatureCollection',
        features: []
    };

    // create geojason layer object
    var commentPoints = L.geoJson(comments, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.comment);
        }
    }).addTo(map);


    // add marker to map & print LatLng coordiantes in console onclick 
    function onMapClick(e) {

        // set comment variable
        var comment = "placholder for comment";

        // get comment from user
        //var comment = getComment();

        // Open the comment modal 
        $( "#myModal" ).show();

        // Save comment and add GeoJSON when user clicks the Save button
        $( "#saveButton" ).click(function() {

            // create temporarpy geojson object
            var commentPoint = {
                "type": "Feature",
                "id": null, // null for now
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [e.latlng.lng, e.latlng.lat] //get coordinates from latlng
                },
                "properties": {
                    "name": "John Doe",
                    "comment": comment
                }
            };

            //console.log(commentPoint);
            commentPoints.addData(commentPoint);

            //close the modal
            $( "#myModal" ).hide();

        });


        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal. When the user clicks on <span> (x) or cancle button, close the modal
        $( "#myModal .close, #cancelButton" ).click(function() {

            // close the modal
            $( "#myModal" ).hide();

        });

        // Get the modal. When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        }

    }

    // calls onMapClick function when user clicks the map
    map.on('click', onMapClick);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
$( "#saveButton" ).off().click(function() {
```

Your problem happens, because you add multiple click events to the dialog/ save button. So when you are saveing the second marker, you also call the function to save the first one.

Comment: That fixed my issue. Thanks!